# Android InApp Billing Error: Null data in IAB activity result

Tags: android

I keep getting

> Null data in IAB activity result

I'm trying to implement in-app billing in my app using Android Trivial example. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Donate extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG =
        "TAG HERE";
IabHelper mHelper;
static final String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    //Google play purchase test
    String base64EncodedPublicKey =
            "<My base 64 key>";
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.donate_btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(Donate.this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
                    mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data)
{
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you created the product on google play store account? What kind of testing are you doing - closed alpha or any other?

Comment: I'm using `static final String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";`

Comment: I'm still testing in debug mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've not yet created a product on Google Play Developer Console. Do check out the below tutorials to help you with the process. These are step by step guides to implement In-App Billing in Android Studio:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_Tutorial

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Comment: I'm using static final String ITEM_SKU = **"android.test.purchased"** Do I need to create a product for that also?

Comment: yes. You need to create a product for every SKU_ID at backend. Refer to the tutorial. They'll help you greatly. Follow them step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting, I would also recommend to keep an eye in the [Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html). It is in dev preview, but I would consider it, just to make it easier to migrate.

As Kavach said, check that you added the product.
And, Add this and tell us what you get:

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
   public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
      if (!result.isSuccess()) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
      }
   }
});
```

Last, remember to dispose the helper in onDestroy:

```
if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
```

Comment: Since you have the test product, please let us know what is the result of the startSetup, if this fixed your issue, please accept the answer.